# Incorrect Outbound Message Organization ID?

Tags: webservices, workflowoutboundmessage

I'm trying to check for the organization id, per SF [instructions](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_security.htm), when processing an outbound message in a web service. I am comparing the org Id in the message to one I have put in the settings.settings file. However, the Org ID in the message has "EAI" appended to it. If the org ID in our Company Profile is 00D7700000033K0 the org id in the outbound messages is always 00D7700000033K0EAI. Why is the org ID never correct in the outbound message? Is it safe to just use 00D7700000033K0EAI in the settings file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API always uses 18-character IDs, and so should you. This helps systems that might be case insensitive from confusing "00D7700000033K0" with "00D7700000033k0" (for example).

Comment: So should I use the ID that has "EAI" appended to it? Will these extra characters ever change?

Comment: @Bruno No, they won't change-- they are simply a parity check (the bits are set according to the capital letters in the ID). You can always safely use the 18-character ID, and I'd recommend doing so unless you have some reason not to (I can't think of any good reason, though).

Comment: Thank you very much for the update. I have no problem using the 18 character id. I just needed to know that it wouldn't change at some point and then have that break the application.